# Jupyter notebook name not received from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jupyter-notebook

When I run the following two cells in a Jupyter notebook manually, it prints the name of the notebook:

Cell 1

```
from IPython.core.magics.display import Javascript
Javascript("""
var kernel = IPython.notebook.kernel;
var body = document.body, attribs = body.attributes;
var command = "notebook_name = " + "'" + attribs['data-notebook-name'].value 
+ 
"'";
kernel.execute(command);
""")
```

cell 2:

```
print(notebook_name)
```

However, when I restart the notebook and select run all from the menu, the variabele `notebook_name` is not set.

Does anyone know what is going on?

I've searched many fora, but I still have no idea what it could be ...